# Extract css from a HTML page

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to extract the css codes from serveral HTML files but I can't figure out how to solve the follwing two problems:

1. A HTML file might have more than one block containing CSS code.
2. In HTML CSS is placed inside  tags. But so is other code. I only need the code coming from `<style type="text/css">`.

I looked into beautifulsoup but haven't yet been able to figure out if this is possible using this library or if I need to write something myself.

Hopefully anyone on here can help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code,'html.parser')
soup.find('style',{"type" : "text/css"})
```

I've tried this code on the below html code

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color: powderblue;}
h1   {color: blue;}
p    {color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph1.</p>
<h4>This is a paragraph2.</h4>
<style>
h4   {color: red;}
</style>
```

And this was the output i got -

Output

```
<style type="text/css">  
body {background-color: powderblue;}  
h1   {color: blue;}  
p    {color: red;}  
</style>
```

You can see that i got only the style tag which has `type="text/css"`